# Decomposition of complex system using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, symbolic-math

Consider the following system in complex symbolic form:

```
% syms ix %// or
% syms x  %//?
sys(ix) = ((10+(ix)))/((20+5(ix)+(10(ix))^2+(ix)^3))
```

Where

```
ix = imaginary part
```

Can MATLAB symbolically compute `imag(sys(jx))` and `real(sys(jx))`?

Comment: Sorry about the earlier answer, I was wrong.

Comment: How about `sys(a,b) = (10+(a+1i*b))...`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
syms x
sys(x) = ((10+1.*1i.*x))/(20+(5.*1i.*x)+((10.*1i.*x).^2))+((1.*1i.*x).^3);
imaginaryPart = imag(sys);
```

where the `1i` has been used as opposed to `i`, as it should be more robust according to the [documentation](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/i.html).